# Multiple Relations between two or more id's?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have minimum of two select box in html form to insert through POST but user can add more select boxes.Now i have to show relations between each n every inserted id.

like we have inserted 1,2,3,4 id..so i want it inserted in a table in two column as

```
(1-2) (1-3) (1-4) (2-3) (2-4) (3-4)
```

plzz reply to this and tell some idea about this
any help??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code that you have done so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have html form..i have enclosed screenshot of my form..plz advice me for submitting that form in above required format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate your array and make couples of next elements in same array:

```js
function calculate() {
  var nums = document.getElementById('nums');

  nums = nums
    .value
    .split(',')
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    });

  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
      console.log('(' + nums[i] + ' - ' + nums[j] + ')');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="1,2,5,8" id="nums" />
<button onClick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but sir how i can insert it in database in two columns like---    
 col 1    col  2                               
  1        2
  1         3
  1         4
  2         3
 2          4   so on..

Comment: Pass data to server using Ajax, than use simple query `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ("v1", "v2"), ("v1", "v2")`

Comment: @nik `$.post('url', [[val1, val2], [val1, val2]])`. Try researching.

Comment: can anybody help me on how to insert [ i ] & [ j ] value to two columns of a table through php